# Sublime Text 2 key bindings with sequence of alpha characters

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I have successfully created Key Bindings which insert contents using a combination of keys. For example, an em dash:

```
"keys": ["super+m"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "&mdash;"}
```

But I am now trying to create one which inserts contents using a combination of alpha keys. For example, replacing the name of a font with the CSS font-family declaration:

```
"keys": ["t,i,s,a"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "font-family:\"ff-tisa-web-pro\",\"TisaPro-Regular\",Georgia,serif;"}
```

But it does *nothing* ... if I change the keys to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> it works. Is the sequence of keys method not available or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use ["t", "i", "s", "a"] instead of ["t,i,s,a"]

Comment: @r-stein I prefer the snippet suggestion, as it both introduced me to how simple snippet creation can be, and it allows for the tab trigger. The tab trigger would allow me to type the word Tisa (ex: in commented instructions) in the CSS file without initiating the font-family declaration insert.

Comment: Yes, snippets are better for that scenario. In addition if you have a lot of snippets, then you can consider to combine them into an [completions file](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a regular [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) for this:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro", "TisaPro-Regular", Georgia, serif;
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>tisa</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save the file as `Packages/User/tisa.sublime-snippet` where `Packages` is the folder opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**. You should now be able to type *`tisa`* in CSS files, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and your font-family declaration will show up.

Comment: Fan. Tas. Tic. Thank you for the quick and clear answer. Works *perfectly*

Comment: @CraigTommola no problem. If you find yourself making a lot of snippets, you may want to look into putting together a [completions file](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html). It saves a lot of the boilerplate of snippets, and is easier to track/update.